# xarray - can't read data

Tags: python-2.7, netcdf, python-xarray

After installing the latest version of Anaconda (5.2.0) and xarray (0.10.8), I encountered a problem with reading data files that didn't have any issues before. Here is the output of

```
print xarray.open_dataset(file_name):
```

> <xarray.Dataset>
>   Dimensions:  (x: 80, y: 60)
>   Coordinates:
>     * x        (x) float64 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 10.0 11.0 12.0 ...
>     * y        (y) float64 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 10.0 11.0 12.0 ...
>   Data variables:
>       z        (y, x) float64 ...
>   Attributes:
>       Conventions:  COARDS/CF-1.0

Data variable `z` is not accessed. The same file could be read previously. Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what the problem is here? Perhaps you need to call .load() on the dataset?

Comment: I use 'data = xarray.open_dataset(filename)' to read a 2-D array from a file. The output of print ... should look like  'Data variables:
    z        (y, x) float64 2.463 2.75 3.254 3.505 3.633 3.425 3.373 3.468 ... '

Answer (score 2):

Calling `xarray.open_dataset()` is a lazy operation. In other words, while the metadata in your dataset is read (e.g. dimensions, coordinates and attributes), the actual values in each array is not read. The `...` that you see above is indicating that your data has not been read yet.

There were some somewhat recent changes in xarray that may be causing the confusion on this point. In previous versions of xarray, printing the `Dataset.__repr__` would load a few sample data points for each variable. For various reasons, this feature was removed and replaced with a `...` string, indicating that the data has not been loaded into memory yet.

To load your data into memory, simply call the `.load()` method:

```
ds = xarray.open_dataset(file_name)
print(ds.load())
```